# How to unsubscribe from own written Observable?

Tags: angular

I have 2 observables functions

```
      putToLs(lang): Observable<any> {
        this.languageService.setLanguage(lang);
        return of(true)
      }

      refreshPage(): Observable<any> {
        return of(this.route.url);
      }
```

And I use them in another function

```
 changeLang(lang) {
    const allLangs = this.translate.getLangs();
    this.chosenLang = lang;
    this.listOfLang = [...allLangs].filter(item => item !== this.chosenLang);
    this.translate.use(lang);
    this.putToLs(lang).subscribe(val => {
      if (val) {
        this.refreshPage().subscribe(val => {
          console.log(val)
          this.route.navigate([val]);
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

As you can see I have created own observable to wait once language would be set `putToLs(lang)`. How can I unsubscribe in `this.putToLs(lang).subscribe` and `this.refreshPage().subscribe` , I have seen that I can use `pipe(takeUntil(variable))` but I dont know which variable should I put into `takeUntil()`
**P.S:** Generally , should I unsubscribe from own Observable ? I have read an article on Medium and they say that I should ALWAYS to unsubscribe from observable to avoid memory leaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign your subscribe function to a subscription variable.

You should probably unsubscribe to the previous `refreshPageSub` each time since you are creating a new subscription each time the first subscription is called.

```
let refreshPageSub;
const putToLsSub = this.putToLs(lang).subscribe(val => {
      if (val) {
        refreshPageSub && refreshPageSub.unsubscribe();
        refreshPageSub = this.refreshPage().subscribe(val => {
          console.log(val)
          this.route.navigate([val]);
        })
      }
    })
```

Then, just call `unsubscribe()` on your `putToLsSub` when you are done with it.

```
putToLsSub.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: if I save my function to const subscription , will my code work ? I mean I'm invoking my function  this.putToLs(lang).subscribe and then subcribe to result. If I would just save in variable it will not be invoked, won't it ?

Comment: It will still get invoked. You are just saving the subscription, so you can unsubscribe. Since you are subscribing inside another subscription, you just need to create a variable in the top level for the inner subscription.